# Sorting a hash of arrays using Perl

Tags: perl

```
my %Hash = ( 

   1111 => [5,6] ,
   5555 => [3,4],   
   2222 => [3],
   4444 => [3,1]

)
```

How can i  sort hash by values in ascending order, so that all the values should display as sorting but if elements are equal , sorting of keys should be in descending order.

```
   <p>  Output:  
    1111 => 6
            5,

    5555 => 4
            3 ,

    4444 => 3
            1 ,

    2222 => 3
</p>
```

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: I don't see how that output has the values sorted in ascending order. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean about descending order. Can you show an example? I'll go by the output you show.

I assumed that you didn't want to change the original data (which may not be the case) so I used the map-sort to create an intermediate one. I go through that intermediate result in order and do the fiddly bits to get what you want. Much of the ugliness is to get you the format you wanted.

The [postfix dereference](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) is useful here:

```
use v5.26;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Hash = (
   1111 => [5,6],
   5555 => [3,4],
   2222 => [3],
   4444 => [3,1]
);


foreach my $tuple (
    sort {
        $b->[1][0] <=> $a->[1][0]
        }
    map {
        [ $_, [ sort { $b <=> $a } $Hash{$_}->@* ] ];
        }
    keys %Hash
    ) {
    print my $string = "$tuple->[0] => ";
    my $indent = length $string;
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $tuple->[1]->$#* ) {
        print ' ' x $indent if $i;
        print $tuple->[1][$i];
        print ',' if $i == $tuple->[1]->$#*;
        print "\n";
        }
    }
```

This produces:

```
1111 => 6
        5,
5555 => 4
        3,
4444 => 3
        1,
2222 => 3,
```

Comment: foreach  my  $k ( sort { @{$hash{$b}} <=> @{$hash{$a}} } keys %hash ) {
        print "$k <=> @{ $hash{$k} }\n";
}

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question instead of putting it in comments :)